# Janusgraph : can't open graph with cql backend

Tags: janusgraph

I want to use cql as storage.backend for some test. I run cassandra service locally.

```
λ cqlsh

WARNING: console codepage must be set to cp65001 to support utf-8 encoding on Windows platforms.
If you experience encoding problems, change your console codepage with 'chcp 65001' before starting cqlsh.

Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.9 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
WARNING: pyreadline dependency missing.  Install to enable tab completion.
cqlsh>
```

I think casscandra is run normally.

My conf/janusgraph-cql.properties is

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.cql.keyspace=janusgraph
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
```

Then i run gremlin console and open the graph

```
gremlin> JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-cql.properties')
```

I get error

```
Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin>
```

I find some similar question like [Can not connect JanusGraph to local Cassandra on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367086/can-not-connect-janusgraph-to-local-cassandra-on-mac) and [Janusgraph : Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428742/janusgraph-could-not-instantiate-implementation-org-janusgraph-diskstorage-cq)
But it don't seem right for me. What should I do or did I miss something?

Comment: Can you please also add the stack trace? You get it in the console simply by typing `y`. It should provide additional information about why JanusGraph cannot connect to Cassandra.